# Requisição ajax retorna dados pela metade

Tags: php

**PHP:**

```
<?php
recebedor.php
$cod  = $_POST['codigo'];
echo $cod;

?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'recebedor.php',
        type:'post',
        data:'codigo='+todosEmails,
        success:function(res) {
                console.log(res);
        }

    });
```

Na variável `todosEmails`, tem um código *HTML* e *CSS* juntos, porém só é retornado um pequeno pedaço do código que é esse:

```
    <meta content="0;url=/search?q=Mata de sao joao "@gmail.com""@hotmail.com"
```

**E o código deveria ser este:**

```
<meta content="0;url=/search?q=Mata+de+sao+joao+%22%40gmail.com%22%22%40hotmail.com%22&amp;num=100&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=n0OtWsfaIIyawATRkoSgDQ" http-equiv="refresh"><style>table,div,span,p{display:none}</style><div style="display:block">Clique <a href="/search?q=Mata+de+sao+joao+%22%40gmail.com%22%22%40hotmail.com%22&amp;num=100&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=n0OtWsfaIIyawATRkoSgDQ">aqui</a> se voc� n�o for redirecionado em alguns segundos.</div>Mata de sao joao "@gmail.com""@hotmail.com" - Pesquisa Google#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-left:4px}#gbg{right:0;padding-right:5px}#gbs{background:transparent;position:absolute;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;z-index:998;right:0}.gbto #gbs{background:#fff}#gbx3,#gbx4{background-color:#2d2d2d;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -138px;background-repeat:repeat-x;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:24px;height:29px;_height:30px;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:990}#gbx3{left:0}#gbx4{right:0}#gbb{position:relative}#gbbw{left:0;position:absolute;top:30px;width:100%}.gbtcb{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}#gbz .gbtcb{right:0}#gbg .gbtcb{left:0}.gbxx{display:none !important}.gbxo{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important}.gbm{position:absolute;z-index:999;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;text-align:left;border:1px solid #bebebe;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbrtl .gbm{-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbto .gbm,.gbto #gbs{top:29px;visibility:visible}#gbz .gbm{left:0}#gbg .gbm{right:0}.gbxms{background-color:#ccc;display:block;position:absolute;z-index:1;top:-1px;left:-2px;right:-2px;bottom:-2px;opacity:.4;-moz-border-radius:3px;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);*opacity:1;*top:-2px;*left:-5px;*right:5px;*bottom:4px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5)";opacity:1\0/;t
```

Comment: E o código deveria ser este: NA VERDADE É ALGO QUE CONTEM MAIS DE 90000 MIL CARACTERES MUITO MESMO NEM DEIXOU EU POSTAR TUDO O PROGRAMA DO STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: Coloque mais detalhes sobre o problema como o está querendo fazer, e qual o resultado esperado vs resultado

Comment: Se possível siga o conselho do Sveen e evite escrever em caixa alta, também.

Comment: A requisição POST tem um limite definido no servidor, portanto você deve verificar se nesse limite vai comportar todo o conteúdo que você quer enviar.

Comment: nossa eu nao sabia nossa

Comment: PIKEI TUDO numa mesma pagina

Comment: você pode alterar o arquivo PHP.INI, mais especificamente o campo: max_input_vars. O default dele é 1000 caracteres